# I am not able to import a code from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to import my code functions from one file to another, however, it's not working.

Look at the file I'm exporting from:

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<User>:<PassWord>@cluster0.ubhacr9.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"



const client = new MongoClient(uri);


async function run(){
    //code
}

async function inserirDatabase(tipo, descricao, valor, id){
   //code
}

async function readDatabase (){
    //code
}

async function deleteOneOnDatabase(id){
   //code
}

module.exports = run, inserirDatabase, readDatabase, deleteOneOnDatabase
```

Look how I'm importing the file:
`import {run, inserirDatabase, readDatabase, deleteOneOnDatabase} from '../database/database.js';`

Comment: just change to `module.exports = {run, inserirDatabase, readDatabase, deleteOneOnDatabas}`, then read https://nodejs.dev/en/api/v18/esm/#interoperability-with-commonjs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing module.exports, try adding "export" before each function name. ie:

```
export async function run(){
    //code
}
```

Comment: So with that functionality you told me, would I delete module.exports?

Comment: I did what you said, but it's giving me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score -1):

Export File:

```js
function somefunction1(){
 //codes
}

function somefunction2(){
 //codes
}

module.exports = {
 somefunction1: somefunction1,
 somefunction2: somefunction2
}
```

Import File:

```js
const {somefunction1, somefunction2} = require("path/to/file.js")
somefunction1()
somefunction2()
```